# Connecting HiveServer2 from pyspark

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyspark

I am stuck at point as , how to use pyspark to fetch data from hive server using jdbc.

I am Trying to connect to HiveServer2  running on my local machine from pyspark using jdbc. All components HDFS,pyspark,HiveServer2 are on same machine.

Following is the code i am using to connect :

```
connProps={ "username" : 'hive',"password" : '',"driver" : "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"}
sqlContext.read.jdbc(url='jdbc:hive2://127.0.0.1:10000/default',table='pokes',properties=connProps)
dataframe_mysql = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default").option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver").option("dbtable", "pokes").option("user", "hive").option("password", "").load()
```

both methods used above are giving me same error as below:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
>
> javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection
>   to the given database. JDBC url =
>   jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true, username = APP.
>   Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to
>   start your database after your app).
>
> ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database /home///jupyter-notebooks/metastore_db

metastore_db is located at same directory where my jupyter notebooks are created. but hive-site.xml is having different metastore location. 
I have already checked reffering to other questions about same error saying other spark-shell or such process is running,but its not. Even if i try following command when HiveServer2 and HDFS are down i am getting same error

```
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING) USING hive")
```

I am able to connect to hives using java program using jdbc. Am I missing something here? Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spark should not use JDBC to connect to Hive.

It reads from the metastore, and skips HiveServer2

However, `Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database` means that you're running Spark from another session, such as another Jupyter kernel that's still running. Try setting a different metastore location, or work on setting up a remote Hive metastore using a local Mysql or Postgres database and edit `$SPARK_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml` with that information.

From [SparkSQL - Hive tables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables)

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

# spark is an existing SparkSession
spark.sql("CREATE TABLE...")
```